# addFlashAttribute stopped working after Spring update to 6.0.11

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a project with spring-webmvc 4.0.2 and I've updated it to 6.0.11.
After the update the `RedirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute` seem's to not work anymore.
After i set a `CustomObject` (just a bunch of string fields put together in a custom class) using the `RedirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute` all I manage to retrieve with `@ModelAttribute("details")` is a `CustomObject` where all fields are null.

I've managed to confirm with debugger that the field are not empty before the redirection so it's not just a issue with the values.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mycontroller")
public class MyController {
    @Secured(MyRoles.ROLE_CONSULT)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
    public ModelAndView getMyPage(@ModelAttribute("details") CustomObject details) {
        //Here the details object fields are all null after a redirection, even if the object is full before the redirection. 
    }


    @Secured(RoleRedac.ROLE_EDIT)
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
    public String save(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
      ...
      if (!validateDetails(details)) {
            //Here details is a CustomObject where all fields are assigned to a value. 
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("details", details);
            return "redirect:/ihm/mycontroller/" + id;
      }
      ...

     }
}
```

For now I've bypassed this by using a static HashMap in the controller that use the session id as a key, but I'm aware that it's not the bets approach so I'd like to understand what the issue here.